# Maximum modulus inside a boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $|f (z)| ≤ 1$ at $∂D$. If $f (1/2) = 0$ show that $$\frac{-4}{5}
>  \leq f(-\frac{1}{2}) \leq \frac{4}{5} $$

Any tips? Have been thinking about, but couldn't find out a way to solve it.

Comment: The stated bound can't be right as it implies $f\big(-\frac{1}{2}\big)\in\mathbb R$.  Suppose $f(z) = \frac{i}{2} \cdot \big(z-\frac{1}{2}\big) $, then $f\big(-\frac{1}{2}\big)\not\in\mathbb R$, a contradiction

Comment: did you try Schwarz Pick?

Answer (score 1):

The mapping
$$
g(z)=\frac{z+1/2}{1+z/2}
$$
is one-to-one and one in the unit disk $D$, and takes $\partial D$ to itself and so is
$$
g^{-1}(z)=\frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}
$$

In particular, $f\circ g$ is analytic in a larger disk, $f(g(0))=0$ and $|f(g(z))|\le 1$, for $|z|\le 1$. Schwarz Principle provides that
for $|z|\le1$:
$$
|f(g(z))|\le |z|
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(z)|\le |g^{-1}(z)|=\left|\frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}\right|.
$$
Hence
$$
|f(-½)|\le \left|\frac{-1/2-1/2}{1+¼}\right|=\frac{4}{5}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $$g(z) = \frac{2z - 1}{2 - z}.$$ Then $g$ has a single (simple) zero in $D$ at $z=\tfrac12$ and $\lvert g(z) \rvert = 1$ if $\lvert z \rvert=1$.  Therefore $f/g$ is holomorphic on $D$ and, by the maximum principle, $\lvert f/g \rvert \leq 1$ on $D$.  Now take $z=-\tfrac12$.